# Will the Sun's fast (but subluminal) removal cause gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves, solar-system, ligo

Reading this question 
[How fast does gravity propagate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/how-fast-does-gravity-propagate),
I'm curious over the consequences of the sun being removed.

As should be clear, we cannot just remove the sun as it violates energy conservation. We can however let the Sun accelerate fast (but subluminal) out of the solar system.

Assuming this (unreasonable) scenario, will this fast disappearance of Sun cause any gravitational wave signature? Basically would and experiment such as [LIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) be able to measure a gravitational signature of the Sun's removal.

INTUITION: The intuition I'm having here is that if the Sun is removed quickly there could be ripples in the space-time in the wake of the Suns path out of the solar-system, and these could be detected.

Comment: Aren't you basically asking if an accelerating object creates gravitational waves? In which case see [Does an object creates gravitational waves when only accelerating in one direction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256521/does-an-object-creates-gravitational-waves-when-only-accelerating-in-one-directi)

Comment: Your Intuition is true.

Comment: We have plenty of instruments that can measure the removal of the sun.

Comment: @JohnRennie I suppose i am, than you for pointing that out.

Comment: Basically would and experiment such as LIGO be able to measure a gravitational signature of the Sun's removal. - Even I myself, sitting on the sofa in my apartment, would be able to measure the gravitational signature of the Sun's removal :) Gravitational waves aren't the only kind of observable effects of such an event.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I also understand that most obvious effect would be the disappearance of the sun (after 8 minutes). But if you ignore that elephant in he room, it's not obvious -- at least no to me -- that we would be able to feel (just sitting in a sofa) the (lack of) acceleration caused by starting to move tangentially from our usual orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *linear* acceleration of the sun would indeed cause gravitational waves - it is the acceleration of mass that does so provided that the mass distribution is not spherical.

But, if the mass is truly spherically symmetrical it can expand/contract as fast and as much as you want and no gravitational waves will be emitted. This is due to [Birkhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) (Wikipedia link).

So if the sun were to be removed by accelerating all its mass outwards but in a spherically symmetric way (as though it exploded very neatly) no gravitational waves would be generated.

Gravitational waves are however expected from real explosions such as supernovae because the mass distribution is not perfectly spherically symmetric - as evidenced by the observed residual motion "the supernova kick" of remnant neutron stars and the forms of supernova-generated nebulae.

Comment: See this question for 'Monopole Gravitational Waves' in the symmetry scenario. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154899/monopole-gravitational-waves-exist